# SearchKick get total results count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I am using `SearchKick` for searching the data. And i am performing pagination. How can i get the total result count in this case:

My searchkick result:

```
       #<Searchkick::Results:0x007faeeef8ed88
   @facets=nil,
   @max_score=0.0,
   @options=
    {:load=>true,
     :payload=>
      {:query=>{:match_all=>{}},
       :size=>20,
       :from=>0,
       :sort=>{"created_at"=>:desc},
       :filter=>{:and=>[{:term=>{"sub_category_id"=>2}}]},
       :fields=>[]},
     :size=>20,
     :from=>0,
     :term=>"*"},
   @response=
    {"took"=>4,
     "timed_out"=>false,
     "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0},
     "hits"=>
      {"total"=>1925,
       "max_score"=>nil,
       "hits"=>
        [{"_index"=>"products_..", "_type"=>"product", "_id"=>"..", "_score"=>nil, "sort"=>[..]},....]}},
   @results=
    [#<Product>,...]....
```

One more thing i am not able to do:

```
SearchKickResult.response
```

It returns me error saying:

`undefined method`response'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searchkick provides a `#total_count` method which counts the total hits of the response:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/7a24684bb470abd5ceca7a40b21d28584b910a4c/lib/searchkick/results.rb#L89

```
def total_count
  response["hits"]["total"]
end
alias_method :total_entries, :total_count
```

Answer (score 2):

In searchkick (0.9.0) it is: 
`response.total_count`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one :-**

*data* = **Model_name**.*search* '*'

*data.results.count*